# How to duplicate all files in a given folder with auto renaming

Tags: command-line, copy

What I basically want to do is take all files in a directory and make a copy of them within the same directory therefore doubling the directory size.

When I try to use cp however, it keeps telling me they are the same file which is the point.

Is there a way to copy them while renaming them to (1),(2) etc. like windows does?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something *similar* to Windows behavior, using the `--backup=numbered` option:

```
$ ls dir1
apple  banana  carrot  date  egg  fish  grape  ham
```

then

```
$ for f in dir1/*; do cp -vf --backup=numbered "$f" "$f"; done
'dir1/apple' -> 'dir1/apple.~1~'
'dir1/banana' -> 'dir1/banana.~1~'
'dir1/carrot' -> 'dir1/carrot.~1~'
'dir1/date' -> 'dir1/date.~1~'
'dir1/egg' -> 'dir1/egg.~1~'
'dir1/fish' -> 'dir1/fish.~1~'
'dir1/grape' -> 'dir1/grape.~1~'
'dir1/ham' -> 'dir1/ham.~1~'
```

giving

```
$ ls dir1
apple      banana.~1~  date      egg.~1~   grape      ham.~1~
apple.~1~  carrot      date.~1~  fish      grape.~1~
banana     carrot.~1~  egg       fish.~1~  ham
```

Note that `-f` (or `--force`) is still required to override the default "same file" behavior.